# Sending Http Request headers Referer using response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I am using `Response.Redirect(url);` to redirect to another server for login, but that server is expecting HTTP Request header of Referrer. How do I make sure that is always passed through with a value of my servers web address?

I understand that spoofing a click in hidden  HTML is the best way, but not sure the best way to implement in ASP.Net using C#6

Comment: what you need to pass in the referrer

Comment: the web address of my site

Comment: You can't do this from the server side, if the referrer is correctly set by the client that loads the page that runs your code you can return markup or JavaScript that performs a redirect by submitting a form.

Comment: can you give me an example using response.redirect please?